# Create Sorting Options in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I am new to Django and in need of some help. I have my database entries being displayed on a template (6 entries). I am aware that to sort your database objects, you need to write `Model_Name.objects.all().order_by('Choose_Sort_Option')` in the views.py. I would like to make this function a link in that same template. So far, the only thing I've been able to come up with is making a new view, new url pattern, and new template just to display that one new sort. I don't want have to make 30 pages just for sorting. I am thinking that I need to assign that line of code above to a variable(see `product d` and `product_a` below). Then i would call that variable in the template, but I'm not sure how to replace the existing list of database items. In short: How do I create clickable links to sort my database objects all within the same template. This is already done in the admin. Thank you!

my views.py:

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpRequest
from django.contrib import messages
from vendor_db.models import Itemo
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect,
render_to_response, render, redirect, get_object_or_404

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'vendor_db/index.html')

def vendors(request):
    items = Itemo.objects.all()
    var_2 = request.GET.get("q")
    product_d = Itemo.objects.all().order_by('-Product_Name')
    product_a = Itemo.objects.all().order_by('Product_Name')
    if var_2:
        items = items.filter(Vendor_Name__icontains=var_2)

    context = {'items': items,
    'product_d' :product_d,
    'product_a' :product_a,
    }

    return render(request, 'vendor_db/vendors.html', context)
```

my template (it is already displaying all of my database objects in an arbitrary order):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

    <h2>All Vendors</h2>
    <h3>Search</h3><div>
    <form method='GET' action=''>
        <input type='text' name="q" placeholder='Search Vendors'/>
        <input type='submit' value='Search'/>
            <form action="{% url 'vendors' %}"> 
                <input type="submit" value="Reset">
            </form>
    </form>
    <br>
{% if items %}
        {% for stuff in items %}    
            <a href="{% url 'vendors_detail' stuff.id %}">
            {{ stuff.Product_Name|capfirst }}<div></div>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No Results Found</p>
{% endif %}

        <h3>Sort by:</h3>
        <a href="{% url 'product_name_asc' %}">Product Name</a>        
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT**
While I am sure the 2 answers below would the do the trick, I was unable to comprehend (my own fault). I places my database entries in a table and used a [javascript library](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) to change the sort order just by clicking the column header. You can see the question I asked and the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138669/how-to-use-django-cycle-tag/36138839#36138839)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model.py class use

```
Class XYZ()
   ...................
   ...................

   class Meta:
       ordering = [
                "your_first_field_name",
                "your_second_field_name",
                ........................
            ]
```

Comment: This does allow me to choose exactly how I want to order it, but this doesn't this make a default way of ordering it? I want to turn this feature into an option, a clickable option. My apologies, as I'm not knowledgeable enough yet in Django to know what I can do with this meta class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a form with a variable as you said, pass the form back to the same view and get the sort option from that and create the sorted query for your product items dynamically or using if statements. Then rerender the page. This means only one view would be needed.

Or you may be interested in an app called django-tables2, it gives you the ability to render a nice table which can then be sorted as you wish by clicking on arrows.

Comment: Wouldn't using a form create unnecessary fields? I just want to display the model entries. How would a form change up my current layout? Lastly, I know how to redirect to the same page, but I am not sure how to replace the database content that lived before it. If you could provide some pseudo code, it might help me wrap my head around it. Thanks again for help!